# setStatusCode() in a JSON is returning headers inside the body

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm developing an API using PHP and Symfony 5.

In the authentication method, I need to return a JWT Token, and the headers with code `201 Created`, so I used this code:

```
// RETURN MESSAGE
$body = [
    'auth_token' => $jwt,
];
$json = new JsonResponse($body);
$json->setStatusCode(201, "Created");
return new Response($json);
```

Where `$jwt` was generated previously.

With this, I was expecting to get a header with the `201 Created` code, and a body with the JWT token, but what I am getting (using Postman) is this:

[image]

As you can see, everything is getting inside the body and the header real code is `200 Ok`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The image you posted clearly says `HTTP/1.0 201 Created`. Where is the `200 OK` response?

Comment: @axiac you are looking at the body of the response. look on the upper right to see the actual response code.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. Something is very wrong in your code. You should `return $json`. The current code produces a new response object (`new Response()`) that contains `$json` as a body. This probably calls `$json->toString()` and what should have been the entire response is used as the body of the returned object.

Comment: Yup, I've already posted an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be returning the `JsonResponse`.

But you are for some reason wrapping the `JsonResponse` on another `Response` object.

Just do:

```
$body = [
        'auth_token' => $jwt,
];

$json = new JsonResponse($body);
$json->setStatusCode(201, "Created");

return $json;
```

I assumue you are calling `setStatusCode()` because you want to set some type of custom text to the response header. But if you are setting the default "Created", you can simply set the status code when instantiating the `JsonResponse` object:

```
return new JsonResponse($payload, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
```

A `JsonResponse` object already extends `Response`, it's simply a convenient way to create a response with `application/json` Content-Type headers, and to automatically encode to JSON whatever payload you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @yivi answer but you can set the status code directly on the constructor

```
$body = [
    'auth_token' => $jwt,
];

return new JsonResponse($body, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
```